# Haskell: Data.Text vs. Data.Text.Lazy Performance

Tags: performance, haskell

for training i wrote a short Haskell program as a replacement for a Perl script.
The program reads a log file which contains multi-line messages and simply joins them to produce one line per message.
My test input file has 14000 lines and a size of 1 MB.
The version using Data.Text has a runtime of 3.5 secs, the one using Data.Text.Lazy only 0.1 secs (the original perl script needs 0.2 secs).
I found in other posts that using Data.Text.Lazy would only make sense for really great amounts of data and didn't expect such a difference.
Can anybody explain the reason why or what's wrong with my program ?

The relevant part of the source (the only difference between both versions is the import Data.Text*):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where
import Data.Char (isDigit)
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy    as T
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as T
import System.Environment (getArgs, getProgName)
import System.IO (openFile, stdin, stdout, Handle,
                  IOMode(ReadMode,WriteMode))

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (inp,out) <- getInput
  actLog <- T.hGetContents inp
  let newLog = processLog actLog
  T.hPutStr out newLog

processLog :: T.Text -> T.Text
processLog = foldr joinLines "" . T.lines

joinLines :: T.Text -> T.Text -> T.Text
joinLines elem accu
  | T.length elem == 0    = accu                     -- Blank Line
  | T.head elem   == ' '  = textElem <> accu         -- Continuation
  | isDigit (T.head elem) = "\n" <> textElem <> accu -- Start
  | otherwise             = accu                     -- Garbage
    where textElem = T.strip elem
```

Comment: Question aside, this is a use case begging for `conduit` or `pipes`.

Comment: The `getInput` identifier isn't in scope, is it defined elsewhere in your program or imported from somewhere?

Comment: getInput is defined elsewhere, based on the command line arguments it returns stdin or an open file handle for input and stdout or a file handle for output

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a data structures issue rather than a laziness issue. A strict `Text` is essentially a single big chunk of memory, while a lazy `Text` is essentially a linked list of strict `Text`s ("chunks"). The way that a lazy `Text` is split up into chunks isn't supposed to be part of the meaning of the value (which is just the text obtained by concatenating all the chunks). But it can have a big effect on the cost of operations.

You have a bunch of operations of the form `short <> accu` where `accu` is growing with the size of your output. If these are strict `Text`s, this concatenation has to copy the entire contents of both `short` and `accu` into a new strict `Text` value. The total runtime is necessarily quadratic. If they are lazy `Text`s, then `<>` has another option: it can prepend the list of chunks that is `short` to the list of chunks that is `accu`. This doesn't need to touch `accu` at all, but even if it did, the spine of the linked list of chunks that makes up `accu` could be much less data to process than the entire textual contents of `accu`, depending on the chunk size. That's why your lazy `Text` version is so much faster.

It looks like you could write your program in the form

```
processLog = T.unlines . processLines . T.lines
processLines :: [T.Text] -> [T.Text]
processLines = ...
```

which leaves the problem of how to concatenate up to the library function `T.unlines`, in which case you can expect it to be efficient whether you use strict `Text` or lazy `Text`.

Comment: After rewriting the program as suggested both versions have the same runtime

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the lazy and normal Data.Text is whether the entire file is read into memory at

```
actLog <- T.hGetContents inp
```

When processed lazy Haskell reads only the line directly required to produce the output. So instead of reading the entire file and then processing and writing as needed, it can now read, write and process as needed eliminating the wait for the entire file to be read in memory.

Comment: i understand this, but the programs reads and processes the complete file in both cases. I don't think that reading a one MB file in one block should take 35 times longer than reading line by line.

Comment: The memory footprint is also a lot smaller. but i agree it only explains part of the speed increase. you could force memory usage  and kill some of the Lazyness by changing " let newLog = processLog actLog" to  "newLog <- processLog actLog"  see if that kills the speed in the same order as using the non lazy Data.Text

Comment: "newLog <- processLog actLog" does not compile

Comment: my bad forgot to wrap that in a monad "newLog <- return $ processLog actLog" should compile. But not shure if it actualy forces the strictness.

Comment: yes, this does compile but the runtime is still the same